# Getting URLs from Page and also the next pages

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I am trying to get all the url links from the page. I am using this link

```
https://www.horizont.net/suche/?OK=suchen&OK=suchen&i_sortfl=pubdate&i_sortd=desc&i_q=der
```

This link is based on search query which shows different articles. There are about 9 articles in each page. So i would like to get all the URLs links as a list from the page.

The second step i want to try, when all the links from the page are extracted from the page then it automatically opens the second page and fetch all the links from there.

[image]

So, s there are about 15194 pages so i would like to get all hyperlinks for articles from the pages.

So far i am trying to do this:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re

def getLinks(url):
    html_page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)
    links = []

    for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^http://")}):
        links.append(link.get('href'))

    return links

print( getLinks("https://www.horizont.net/suche/?OK=suchen&OK=suchen&i_sortfl=pubdate&i_sortd=desc&i_q=der") )
```

The porblem i am facing now is that i am getting every url from the website but i need only which are search results and also for next pages from the search results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the element class attribute of the link you need to extract the href:

```
for link in soup.findAll ('a', attrs = {'href': re.compile ("^ http: //")}, class _ = "ArticleTeaserSearchResultItem_link"):
```

And if you are going to browse all the pages and collect all the url of the articles, I can advise you to change the Page value in the link itself until the link is valid:

```
i = 1
urls = []
while True:

    url = f"https://www.horizont.net/suche/?OK=1&i_q=der&i_sortfl=pubdate&i_sortd=desc&currPage={i}"
    try:
        def getLinks(url):
            html_page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)
            links = []

            for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^http://")}, class_="ArticleTeaserSearchResultItem_link"):
                links.append(link.get('href'))

            return links

    urls.append(getLinks(url))

    except:
        break

    i += 1
```

At this time I haven't opportunity to debug my code but I hope I helped you. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @mind-protector seems the best solution. Let me check. :)

Comment: can i ask why you used here  `url = f"https://www.horizont.net/suche/?OK=1&i_q=der&i_sortfl=pubdate&i_sortd=desc&currPage={i}`   you used "f" before provinding url, why?

Comment: Because I pass the parameter i to this line, thus navigating through the pages of this site

Comment: Ok thanks. The function is running since half hour but im still waiting to get output

Comment: any way that i can get results on run time?